# PySpark - How to loop through the dataframe and match against another common value in another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

This is a recommender system and I have a `Dataframe` which contains about 10 recommended item for each user (`recommendation_df`) and I have another `Dataframe` which consist of the recent purchases of each user (`recent_df`).

I am trying to code out this task but I can't seem to get along the syntax, and the manipulation

I am implementing a hit/miss ratio, basically for every `new_party_id` in `recent_df`, if any of the `merch_store_code` matches the `merch_store_code` for the same `party_id` in the `recommendation_df`, `count +=1` (Hit)

Then calculating the hit/miss ratio by using `count/total user count`

(However in recent_df, each user might have multiple recent purchases, but if any of the purchases is in the list of recommendations_list for the same user, take it as a hit (count +=1)

recommendation_df

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------+----------+
|party_id_index|merch_store_code|     rating|  party_id|
+--------------+----------------+-----------+----------+
|           148|       900000166|  0.4021678|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168339566| 0.27687865|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168993309| 0.15999989|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168350313|  0.1431974|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168329726| 0.13634883|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168351967|0.120235085|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168993312| 0.11800903|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168337234|0.116267696|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168993256| 0.10836013|G18B00332C|
|           148|       168339482| 0.10341005|G18B00332C|
|           463|       168350313| 0.93455887|K18M926299|
|           463|       900000072|  0.8275664|K18M926299|
|           463|       700012303| 0.70220494|K18M926299|
|           463|       700012180| 0.23209469|K18M926299|
|           463|       900000157|  0.1727839|K18M926299|
|           463|       700013689| 0.13854747|K18M926299|
|           463|       900000166| 0.12866624|K18M926299|
|           463|       168993284|0.107065596|K18M926299|
|           463|       168993269| 0.10272527|K18M926299|
|           463|       168339566| 0.10256036|K18M926299|
+--------------+----------------+-----------+----------+
```

recent_df

```
+------------+---------------+----------------+
|new_party_id|recent_purchase|merch_store_code|
+------------+---------------+----------------+
|  A11275842R|     2022-05-21|       168289403|
|  A131584211|     2022-06-01|       168993311|
|  A131584211|     2022-06-01|       168349493|
|  A131584211|     2022-06-01|       168350192|
|  A182P3539K|     2022-03-26|       168341707|
|  A182V2883F|     2022-05-26|       168350824|
|  A183B5482P|     2022-05-10|       168993464|
|  A183C6900K|     2022-05-14|       168338795|
|  A183D56093|     2022-05-20|       700012303|
|  A183J5388G|     2022-03-18|       700013650|
|  A183U8880P|     2022-04-01|       900000072|
|  A183U8880P|     2022-04-01|       168991904|
|  A18409762L|     2022-05-10|       168319352|
|  A18431276J|     2022-05-14|       168163905|
|  A18433684M|     2022-03-21|       168993324|
|  A18433978F|     2022-05-20|       168341876|
|  A184410389|     2022-05-04|       900000166|
|  A184716280|     2022-04-06|       700013653|
|  A18473797O|     2022-05-24|       168330339|
|  A18473797O|     2022-05-24|       168350592|
+------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Here is my current coding logic:

```py
count = 0
def hitratio(recommendation_df, recent_df):
 for i in recent_df['new_party_id']:
  for j  in recommendation_df['party_id']:
   if (i = j) & i.merch_store_code == j.merch_store_code:
    count += 1
  return (count/recent_df.count())
```

Comment: Your example is quite bad. You don't see matches in it. It would be best if you posted full example inputs and the expected output made directly from those inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, refrain from loops on rows. Spark does not work like that, you need to think of the whole column, not about row-by-row scenario.

You need to join both tables and select users, but they need to be without duplicates (distinct)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_distinct_matches = (
    recent_df
    .join(recommendation_df, F.col('new_party_id') == F.col('party_id'))
    .select('party_id').distinct()
)
hit = df_distinct_matches.count()
```

Comment: yes, I think this matches the user, but how do I implement this  "basically for every new_party_id in recent_df, if any of the merch_store_code matches the merch_store_code for the same party_id in the recommendation_df, count +=1 (Hit)" Thanks for replying

Comment: Please describe more in detail - what is not implemented? The variable `hit` holds the finalized `count`. It's already implemented. You don't need loops, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

assumption :
i am taking all the count rows of recent df as denominator for calculating the hit/miss ratio you can change the formula.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
matching_cond = ((recent_df["merch_store_code"]==recommender_df["merch_store_code"]) &(recommendation_df["party_id"].isNotNull()))

df_recent_fnl= df_recent.join(recommendation_df,df_recent["new_party_id"]==recommendation_df["party_id"],"left")\
.select(df_recent["*"],recommender_df["merch_store_code"],recommendation_df["party_id"])\
.withColumn("hit",F.when(matching_cond,F.lit(True)).otherwise(F.lit(False)))\
.withColumn("hit/miss",df_recent_fnl.filter(F.col("hit")).count()/df_recent.count())
```

do let me know if you have any questions around this .

If you like my solution , you can upvote